Axler LADR 3rd Edition $9A$ $Q13$: Prove a null space has even dimension
This question was taken from Sheldon Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd edition. It is chapter 9 (operators on real vector spaces), Q13. The question is:
Suppose $V$ is a real vector space, $T\in{\mathcal{L}}(V)$, and $b,c\in\mathbb{R}$ are such that $b^2 < 4c$. Prove that $\text{null }(T^2+bT+cI)^j$ has even dimension for every positive integer j.

I have done tried this question and have written down the following proof. I found a proof online that goes down the route of proving $\text{null }(T_\mathbb{C}^2+bT_{\mathbb{C}}+cI)^j=\text{null }(T_{\mathbb{C}}-\lambda)^j\oplus\text{null }(T_{\mathbb{C}}-\bar{\lambda})^j$, and the final result follows soon after this. I did something different, and I am not sure if certain steps are allowed/correct. Any feedback for my attempted proof would be appreciated.

Clearly, $(T^2+bT+cI)|_{\text{null }(T^2+bT+cI)^j}$ is nilpotent. We conclude from Q12 that $T|_{\text{null }(T^2+bT+cI)^j}$ has no eigenvalues.
Let $v_1,...,v_{2n+1}\in V$ be chosen such that $n$ is the smallest nonnegative integer such that the list spans $\text{null }(T^2+bT+cI)^j$.
We will prove that the list is linearly dependent, hence $v_1,...,v_{2n}$ is a basis of $\text{null }(T^2+bT+cI)^j$, with even dimension.
To do so, suppose not. That is, suppose $v_1,...,v_{2n+1}$ is linearly independent.
From Q3, we know that $v_1,...,v_{2n+1}$ must also be linearly independent in $(\text{null }(T^2+bT+cI)^j)_\mathbb{C}=\text{null }(T_\mathbb{C}^2+bT_\mathbb{C}+cI)^j$. But then, due to the choice of $n$, we have $\text{dim null }(T_\mathbb{C}^2+bT_\mathbb{C}+cI)^j=2n+1$ and so there is a real eigenvalue of $T_\mathbb{C}|_{\text{null }(T_\mathbb{C}^2+bT_\mathbb{C}+cI)^2}$, so $T|_{\text{null }(T^2+bT+cI)^j}$ has an eigenvalue, a contradiction.

Below is images of the two questions referenced in my proof.


